# Which oracle version liquibase supports

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I am new to `Liquibase` software and planning to use it for Oracle.

Does `Liquibase` support all versions of Oracle or it support only from any particular version?

Comment: Which versions of Oracle do you need to support?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it supports most recent versions of Oracle. Specific Oracle features may not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [plain sql migrations](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) with Liquibase, therefore it supports any Oracle version it can connect via jdbc.